# Listagg alternative in db2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

My customer is using db2 database without listagg function, but I need to somehow aggregate the primary key information within one field.

Right now (for Oracle) I am using this as a part of bigger query:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME || ':' || CONTENT, ',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME || ':' || CONTENT) 
FROM TABLE
WHERE ROW_IDENTIFIER_ID = I.REC_ID AND I.TABLE_RESULT_ID = T.REC_ID
```

It there an alternative way to get result of listagg function in db2 database before  DB2 as of version 9.7 Fix Pack 4<sup>[1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.databases.ibm-db2/LTFwkp2LCro/ofpyPJ30SUAJ)</sup> ?

Version of my customer's database:
Linux - Enterprise server edition 9.7, release number 08060107 
I got it by executing these selects:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ENV_GET_INST_INFO()) AS SYSTEMINFO;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ENV_GET_PROD_INFO()) AS SYSTEMINFO;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ENV_GET_SYS_INFO()) AS SYSTEMINFO;
```

I admit I don't understand, how can it be 9.7, but there is not listagg function?! :confused:

I also did executed:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.FUNCTIONS
```

I got back this [function list](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86812066/function_list.xlsx), but there are no functions like xmltext or xmlgroup mentioned in alternative solutions down in the answers:(.
What neanderthal database is the customer using? Or am I missing something?

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: See if [this workaround](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/aggregating_strings42?lang=en) fits your needs.

Comment: Which DB2 server are you using: DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS? And which version? Different DB2 platforms have different sets of built-in functions.

Comment: Updated question with version info and function list.

Comment: I believe the XML extensions are optional, so they may not be installed.  It's actually possible to do this with a recursive CTE (I've done this on an AS/400); unfortunately, I no longer have access to an instance to work against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your version of DB2 supports pureXML (that would be at least DB2 for LUW 9.1 and I believe DB2 9 for z/OS), in addition to what @PM77-1 suggested above, you could use the XMLAGG function:

```
select xmlserialize(
  xmlagg(
    xmlconcat(
      xmltext(column_name),
      xmltext(':'),
      xmltext(content),
      xmltext(',')
    )
  ) as varchar(10000)
) 
from 
  yourtable 
...
```

Comment: PureXML support is surprisingly available, but functions are not listed in the select mentioned in the question.
Together with workaround tip from  PM 77-1 I managed to find a solution. Many thanks.

Comment: "I managed to find a solution" Would be awesome if you could share the solution you found...