# Concatenating Strings, based on Case Statement

Tags: sql, db2

I need to append notes onto a daily report where notes are stored in a different table based on the values.

i.e. The notes are stored in a notes table, on multiple records, a LineNo Column with values 1,2,3 etc. based on the Number of Records in the Notes. **The number of notes line is variable**

I want to Select the Notes and Concatenate these 3 fields together in the output as a single column;

i.e.:

```
Select (Concat Notes Line1, Notes Line2 Notes Line3), 
       UserName, 
       NotesDate
From   notes 
Where  NoteType=2 
and    RefNo in (SELECT RefNo from Report);
```

I've looked at various solutions using Case and Concat but none seem to work. There is already a Join in the stored procedure to create the report.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098582/listagg-alternative-in-db2

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

`Select Line1 || Line2 || Line3, 
       UserName, 
       NotesDate
From   notes 
Where  NoteType=2 
and    RefNo in (SELECT RefNo from Report)`

If you insist on using the concat command (which is functionally equal to ||), the following would work:

`Select concat(concat(Line1,Line2),Line3), 
       UserName, 
       NotesDate
From   notes 
Where  NoteType=2 
and    RefNo in (SELECT RefNo from Report)`

The concat() command in DB2 can only handle two arguments, which is why a nested concat() is needed.

Comment: I should have specified that there is only records in Line No if there are one or more lines of notes entered.

Comment: You could add a 'case when line is not null' to my examples. On another note, why not save all lines in a single 'line' column?

Comment: Instead of the potentially problematic "||" operator, the "CONCAT" operator can be used for explicit concatenation (at least in most DB2 variants).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the SYSadmin and can't change the table. I don't know why it was designed like that, but all entity related notes are stored like that in the Application. i.e. a record for each line on the input screen.