# Concatenate Multiple Row Values into 1 Row, with SQL for iSeries

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

First, I need to thank Kent Milligan and his article at http://www.mcpressonline.com/sql/techtip-combining-multiple-row-values-into-a-single-row-with-sql-in-db2-for-i.html for getting me as far in this problem as I have.  But now I need to expand on what he has done here.

To avoid you having to go to his article, the problem he addressed was concatenating string data from multiple rows into a single row in the resulting table.  For example:

Table Cars:

- Make      Model
- Ford      Fusion
- Chevy     Tahoe
- Honda     Odyssey
- Ford      Taurus
- Ford      Focus
- Chevy     Malibu

Results:

- Make      Model
- Chevy     Malibu, Tahoe
- Ford      Focus, Taurus, Fusion
- Honda     Odyssey

This was done with the SQL statement:

```
WITH numbered_sets(make, model, curr, prev) AS (
   SELECT make, model,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY make ORDER BY model) AS curr,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY make ORDER BY model) -1 AS prev
   FROM inventory)
SELECT make,
       MAX (TRIM(L ',' FROM
             CAST(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(model, ',') AS VARCHAR(256)) ))
FROM numbered_sets
START WITH curr = 1
CONNECT BY make = PRIOR make AND prev = PRIOR curr
GROUP BY make
```

I was able to adapt that to my own table, and get most of the way where I wanted to get.  But for my purposes, I have an additional column I need to include for the grouping.  For example:

Table Cars:

- Make      Type        Model
- Ford      Sedan       Fusion
- Chevy     SUV     Tahoe
- Honda     Minivan Odyssey
- Ford      Sedan       Taurus
- Ford      Sedan       Focus
- Chevy     Sedan       Malibu
- Ford      SUV     Escape
- Ford      SUV     Explorer
- Chevy     Sedan       Impala

For the Results, I’d be looking for:

- Make      Type        Model
- Chevy     Sedan       Malibu, Impala
- Chevy     SUV     Tahoe
- Ford      Sedan       Fusion, Taurus, Focus
- Ford      SUV     Escape, Explorer
- Honda     Minivan Odyssey

Does anyone have any thoughts on what all I need to add to the original statement to be able to add the TYPE column, and GROUP on that accordingly?  I’ve tried a handful of things, but I suspect I need to do something with the CONNECT_BY_PATH statement, I’m just not sure what.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to integrate type at the correct points thoughtout the query.

without being able to test, I think this would be close; but I may have missed something...

```
WITH numbered_sets(make, type, model, curr, prev) AS (
   SELECT make, type, model,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY make, Type ORDER BY Make, Type, model) AS curr,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY make, type ORDER BY Make, type, model) -1 AS prev
   FROM inventory)
SELECT make, Type
       MAX (TRIM(L ',' FROM
             CAST(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(model, ',') AS VARCHAR(256)) ))
FROM numbered_sets
START WITH curr = 1
CONNECT BY make = PRIOR make AND prev = PRIOR curr and type = prior type
GROUP BY make, type
```

Perhaps we need do change the connect by to do a concat before connect by... though I can't see why this would help yet...

```
CONNECT BY concat(make,type) = PRIOR concat(make,type) AND prev = PRIOR curr
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I had thought something like that might work, but it doesn't.  What I ended up with was:Chevy SUV Tahoe; Chevy Sedan Tahoe, Malibu, Impala; Ford SUV Escape, Explorer; Ford Sedan Escape, Explorer, Fusion, Taurus, Focus.  It appears to be breaking on the Type, but when it's doing the connection, it's adding all of the results.

Comment: That's odd because in the connect by I added type = prior type. so that it would only traverse the connection by make and type. thus only models for the same make/type should have been connected.

Comment: Ahh, well, I missed your addition to the CONNECT BY line, which is why I had the issue I saw (sorry about that).  I have now added that, but still have an issue.  Now I am only getting 1 line for each Make.  Chevy  SUV  Tahoe; Ford  SUV  Escape, Explorer.

Comment: I must not understand the question, I thought that's the results you were after:  Like makes/types combined on one line with model comma separated after for the same make/type.

Comment: I think you do understand what I am looking for.  However, my results are just 1 Type per Make.  I was expecting Chevy  SUV  Tahoe; Chevy  Sedan  Malibu, Impala; Ford  SUV  Escape, Explorer; Ford  Sedan  Fusion, Focus, Taurus.  But instead of each Type being listed, only 1 Type is being reported for each Make, with its appropriate Models.  Chevy  SUV  Tahoe; Ford  SUV  Escape, Explorer.  The other combinations  Chevy  Sedan  Impala, Malibu; Ford  Sedan  Fusion, Focus, Taurus, are not returned.

Comment: I'm not as familiar iwth the iSeries SQL vs others.  So can you tell me if the iSeries supports ListAgg function or Pure XML as in this example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098582/listagg-alternative-in-db2  ListAgg does exactly what you're looking for, as would the XMLAgg  if neither of those two functions are available, then I begin to understand the row_number approach.

Comment: without a db2 or iseries SQL this is challenging for me to brute force out the correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much @xQbert.  I found one other error I made when adapting your solution to my own tables.  Once I corrected that error, I was able to get the results I was expecting, and was able to get the data to appear in the correct sequence.  Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Comment: Glad to be of service.  If my solution didn't match what you ended up with I would recommend posting your final solution and accepting that as the answer and simply up voting mine as "aiding".  I'd rather guide people to the correct activities if this helps someone in the future.