# SQL to return records that do not have a complete set according to a second table

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have two tables.  I want to find the erroneous records in the first table based on the fact that they aren't complete set as determined by the second table.  eg:

```
custID  service  transID
1       20       1
1       20       2
1       50       2
2       49       1
2       138      1
3       80       1
3       140      1

comboID  combinations
1        Y00020Y00050
2        Y00049Y00138
3        Y00020Y00049
4        Y00020Y00080Y00140
```

So in this example I would want a query to return the first row of the first table because it does not have a matching 49 or 50 or (80 and 140), and the last two rows as well (because there is no 20).  The second transaction is fine, and the second customer is fine.

I couldn't figure this out with a query, so I wound up writing a program that loads the services per customer and transid into an array, iterates over them, and ensures that there is at least one matching combination record where all the services in the combination are present in the initially loaded array.  Even that came off as hamfisted, but it was less of a nightmare than the awkward outer joining of multiple joins I was trying to accomplish with SQL.

Taking a step back, I think I need to restructure the combinations table into something more accommodating, but I still can't think of what the approach would be.

Comment: I don't get the task. Why do you need to return just the first row of the first table? Why not the remaining rows with `custID` 1? What is the semantics of `transID` in the first table (should I ignore the `transID`)? `CustID` is referencing to `comboID`?

Comment: The first and last two rows are bad data because they have a service without a counterpart as listed in the combinations column of the second table.  The transID is important.  The second and third rows are a separate transaction, and the 20 and 50 have an entry in the second table making it a legitimate transaction.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand. And the `custId` from the first table has to be equal to the `comboId` when I'm searching for combinations of a transaction?

Comment: No, custID is there to identify the customer, so you are only considering transactions based on the custID and transID.  If there exists a service that does not have a counterpart according to the combinations table then it is invalid.  The fact that customer #1 and customer #2 have valid combinations based on combos #1 and #2 is just coincidental.

Comment: What is the logic behind the combinations column as it sometines shows Y + 5 digits and sometimes Y+6 digits ?

Comment: Typo.  Augh.  Edited.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have DB2 so I have tested on Oracle. However `listagg` function should be there as well. The table `service` is the first table and `comb` the second one. I assume the `service` numbers to be sorted as in the `combinations` column.

```
select service.*
from service 
join 
(
  select S.custid, S.transid
  from
  (
    select custid, transid, listagg(concat('Y000',service)) within group(order by service) as agg 
    from service 
    group by custid, transid
  ) S
  where not exists
  (
    select *
    from comb
    where S.agg = comb.combinations
  )
) NOT_F on NOT_F.custid = service.custid and NOT_F.transid = service.transid
```

I dare to say that your database design does not conform to the first normal form since the `combinations` column is not atomic. Think about it.

Comment: While I am amenable to making a new table for the combinations table as I stated in the original question, listagg seems like it takes two arguments where you have only given one.  And while I don't have listagg on my system, it can be done using this
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467653/concatenate-multiple-row-values-into-1-row-with-sql-for-iseries. I think this is on the right track, though, in making the first table into the format of the second and then seeing if it has an entry.  Thanks man!  I'll get back to you with what I can find.

Comment: I was thinking more about your use case and the fact that `combinations` in the second table is not atomic may be good for your query. Seeking for subsets would be much more computationally intensive. If I return to my solution: `Listagg` is not present in your version of DB2?

Comment: Listagg is part of Db2 since at least Version 9.7

Comment: I am on an as400/iseries/ibmi.  db2 is about as close as I could approximate what I have available.  Also, the second table is a result of "programmers" whimsically creating records to accommodate their logic for other programs they install.  There are only about 18 records in that table, so like I said, if a different structure would help I can just make a new table entirely for my purposes.  The first table is an unkeyed transaction table with ~20,000 records.  The transid is my approximation of transactions based on timestamps that are "similar enough."

Comment: I tried aggregating into one column, but quickly realized that there can be more than one combination on any given transaction.  Aggregating all of the services, then, would not match any of the combinations column rendering this useless.  :(  I really appreciate your attempt, but I still feel like my writing a program was a sort of way of conceding defeat lol.  I can always post the code if you guys are curious, but it is archaic RPGLE that might require eyebleach after viewing.  Thanks again!