# LISTAGG Function Failing in DB2 LUW 9.7 FP5

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-luw, listagg

I'm trying to combine shipping locations of each supplier into a single list per supplier as shown below.

Table data:

```
SUPPLIER_NAME|Ship_from|
Supplier A   |  IOSL1  |
Supplier A   |  IHMI1  |
Supplier A   |  IHMI2  |
```

Desired Query Output:

```
SUPPLIER_NAME|     Ship_from     |
Supplier A   |IOSL1, IHMI1, IHMI2|
```

It looks like LISTAGG is probably the best/simplest way to go about this, but I can't get it to work following the documentation on the DB2 documentation for the LISTAGG function.

SQL:

```
select
    SUPPLIER_ID,
    LISTAGG(PROC_FLO_NAME, ', ') within group (order by PROC_FLO_NAME DESC) as Ship_from 
from rcx.RXPRF1
group by SUPPLIER_ID
```

When I try to run this query, I get an error saying "Illegal use of the keyword GROUP token, FROM INTO was expected" which I haven't been able to figure out why.

I'm using DB2 version 9.7.500.702 Fix Pack 5 (found using db2level command) with QMF 8.1 Fix Pack 15 (Unicode) to run the query.

Comment: Presumably your version of DB2 doesn't support `listagg()`.  `GROUP` is the first syntax error, because it is a reserved word (i.e. it needs to be parsed even before identifiers are looked up).

Answer (score 1):

LISTAGG was introduced into DB2 LUW 9.7 Fix Pack 4.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0056050.html

> Fix Pack 4 also contains the following enhancements:
>       A new aggregate function, LISTAGG, has been added. The LISTAGG function aggregates a set of string elements into one string by concatenating the strings. Optionally, a separator string can be provided which is inserted between contiguous input strings. For more information, see LISTAGG aggregate function.

However you (or your DBA) will need to run `db2updv97` to activate the new function. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588635

(or even better, upgrade to Db2 11.1  ;-)

Comment: I'm assuming this is referring to server side?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be run from the instance owner account and then recycle the instance (`db2stop`/`db2start`)

Comment: According to our DBA the server is running z/OS Mainframe DB2 of version 10.1, which does not support the LISTAGG function. Looks like I'll have to find a different way to do this.

Comment: Yes, LISTAGG is new in Db2 for z/OS 12.0.0 (Function level 501 (activation enabled by APAR PI70535)) https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/wnew/src/tpc/db2z_fl_v12r1m501.html#db2z_fl_v12r1m501__listagg

Comment: You could however use `XMLAGG` instead https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_xmlagg.html  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098582/listagg-alternative-in-db2  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output

Comment: XMLAGG was able to do what I needed